# Open outgoing link in iframe by default?

Tags: jquery, html, iframe, anchor

I have a number of outgoing links on my webpage that I want to open in new tab of browser but inside an `iframe` of my own website.

Currently I am using following code:

```
<a href="www.example.com" target="_blank" onclick="this.href='http://mysite.com/article.php?link=www.example.com'">Example.com</a>
```

It seems not an effective solution (as I read out some stuff with google results), also I have to manually do this thing in every link.

Is there any other way to accomplish this? JQuerysh way will also good for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you want all links to automatically be redirected to an iFrame, without you having to  amend the existing code. In that case, you could create a function which does the redirecting to the iFrame and then using jQuery to select all a elements and add an onlick event.

```
$("a").one("click", function () {
  this.href = 'http://mysite.com/article.php?link=' + this.href;
});
```

You could write some extra code to remove "http://" and to URL encode it.

Comment: if not all `a` tags than? Something like with class-selector?

Comment: I have amended the code so that it doesn't fire the event multiple times if, for example, the link was opened in a new tab twice.

Answer (score 0):

**If you want a frame of your site with an iframe of the url clicked, try this...**

You'll have to make a new page to act as a proxy. It seems you've already figured this out with 'http://mysite.com/article.php?link=www.example.com'. You'll link to the proxy page and the proxy page will hold the iframe. Something like this:

Link:
`<a href="article.php?link=example.com" target="_blank">Example.com</a>`

article.php contains:
`<iframe src="<?php echo $_GET['link']; ?>" />`

Solution has no error handling and does not encode the URL.

**Or, if you want to simply open the link inside the current iframe, use this..**

Link:
`<a href="http://example.com" target="myframe">Example.com</a>`

iFrame:
`<iframe id="myframe" />`

Comment: Well not a solution for me, both cases did not made up to my requirements. You are right I have my PHP page `article.php` which gets a GET param and transfers it to the iframe's `src` but I did not want to show it with `href` of `a` because than it will be showed on hover of cursor which is what i am trying to avoid...